# Passing the value of an item selected in a Gridview to the ViewModel of a different Usercontrol

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

After researching a solution to this for three days, finally I gave up. Now I need your help to solve this.

### Scenario:

I've a GridView in a Usercontrol (Lets say WLMSLogs.xaml) and My GridView ItemSource is binded to a List from the ViewModel (WMLSLogsViewModel.cs)

Lets say the List has 4 items (EventID, Name, Request and Response). BothRequest and Responses are XML Strings.

GridView needs to display some of the List items in RowDetailsTemplate under different tab items. So I'm displaying Request and Response under respective TabItems.

```
<GridView x:Name="WMLSLogGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding WMLSLogModelList}">
<GridView.Columns>      
    <GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"/>
    <GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" Header="UserName"/>     
</GridView.Columns>
<GridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >                                                 
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="Request Xml">
                    <TextBlock text="{Binding Request}"/>
                </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Response Xml">
                <TextBlock text="{Binding Response}"/>
            </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="EventLogs" Tag="{Binding .}">
                    <views:LogEvents  />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

WMLSLogModelList is a Observable collection in WMLSLogsViewModel.cs

So far everything works fine and Grid is displaying data as expected.

Now When User expands any row, he can see two TabItems with request and response.
Here I need to add one more TabItem (LogEvents) besides Request and Response tabs.

This LogEvents tab is going have one more GridView to display (so I added a new View `<views:LogEvents />` in the tab). Here comes the tricky part.

This LogEvents GridView needs to get the data based on the corresponding `Selecteditem` (which is `EventId`), and pass this `EventId` to a different ViewModel (LogEventViewModel.cs) and binds the data to the Inner GridView dynamically. All this has to happen either as I expand the RowDetails section or if I select the Tab LogEvents.

There is no relation between the data items of these two Grids, except getting the Selected EventId of the main GridView and passing this to a different ViewModel then to Domain service to get the inner GridView Data.

### What I did so far

As I mentioned I created a new View UserControl for LogEvents, Placed it under new TabItem(EventLogs) inside row details template of main GridView.

LogEvent UserControl contains a Grid View binded to LogEventsViewModel to get the Collection based on Selected row EventId.

How do I assign the Selected EventId to a new ViewModel and Get the data dynamically?

One Way: As I showed you, I called LogEvents by placing it in side TabItem. whenever I expanded any row, Then It is Initializing the LogEvents page, During that I tried to bind the Datacontext to LogEventsViewModel. But I'm unable to get the Seleted row EventId dynamically. If I get that then I can easily pass it to the LogEventsViewModel constructor.

```
       var _viewModel = new LogEventsViewModel(EventId);
       this.DataContext = _viewModel;            
       InitializeComponent();
```

Other way: 
Pass the selected EventId directly from xaml View binding to that page initialization and then to LogEventsViewModel 
Something like this

```
<views:LogEvents  something="{Binding EventId}"/>
```

Is there any other way to do this?

### Details:

LogEvents.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:LogEventsViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
    <GridView x:Name="LogEventsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"            
                 <GridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />              
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding EventId}" Header="LogEventId"/>  
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Exception}" Header="Exception" />
        </GridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

LogEvents.xaml.cs

```
public int EventId
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(EventIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventIdProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventIdProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("EventId", typeof(int), typeof(ApplicationLog),
    new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEventIdChanged)));

    private static void OnEventIdChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        int LogEventId1 = (int)e.NewValue;
        // Need to assign propery in LogEventsViewModel 
    }
```

LogEventsViewModel.cs

```
WMLCDomainContext _Context = new WMLCDomainContext();
    private QueryableDomainServiceCollectionView<LogEvents> view;
    public int _eventid;       

    public ApplicationLogsViewModel()
    {
        EntityQuery<LogEvents> getLogEventsQuery = _Context.GetApplicationLogListQuery(EventId);
        this.view = new QueryableDomainServiceCollectionView<ApplicationLog>(_Context, getLogEventsQuery );                        
    }

    public IEnumerable View
    {get {return this.view;}}

    public int EventId
    {
        get{return this._eventid;}
        set{_eventid = value;}
    }
```

Comment: I would add another property of the type LogEventsViewModel to the item model and bind it in the same way as you bind the Request and Response properties. But if to choose between two your above-described ways, the second is better and can be achieved by using a dependency property.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Dependency property is the better way to solve this, This is my first time writing DP,So I'm going through the concept behind it, and I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create a dependency property on your LogEventsViewModel and then set up a binding on your LogEvents view, something like this:

```
<views:LogEvents EventId="{Binding EventId}" />
```

Then in LogEvents.xaml.cs you could create your dependency property:

```
    private LogEvents_ViewModel _viewModel
    {
        get { return this.DataContext as LogEvents_ViewModel; }
    }

    public string EventId
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EventIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventIdProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EventId", typeof(string), typeof(LogEvents),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEventIdChanged)));

    private static void OnEventIdChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((LogEvents)d).OnTrackerInstanceChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnEventIdChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._viewModel.EventId = e.NewValue;
    }
```

Comment: KodeKreachor, I created the dependency property in LogEvents.xaml.cs. And now when I select EventLogs Tab then it is calling OnEventIdChanged. From there I to initialize the LogEventsViewModel constructor with EventId to get the data. But the problem is once the initialization happens it is directly getting the Property (ListView) even before calling the domain service. So the ListView is null.

Comment: Is it ok if I add a dependency property on my LogEventsViewModel.cs. I updated my LogEventsViewModel.cs in my question.

Comment: @ravella, you certainly could, but I'd recommend instead of initializing your LogEventsViewModel inside the dependency property's changed event, simply assign the dependency property's new value to the appropriate property on your view model as your view model should already be instantiated. Let me know if you'd like a little guidance on when/where to create your view model.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.I added some code in details section of my question. I got the new value in Dependency property changed event. I tried to assign it to my property in ViewModel (Here I got confused exactly to which property(EventId or Colletion). Should we need to call domain service after this assign propery.  Could you show me in some code like how to update property in ViewModel.

Comment: @ravella, a common convention we've used to access the view model corresponding to a given view is to declare a private instance of the view model class in the code-behind of the view. I updated my example above with an example of this.

Comment: Couple of questions, 1st when I tried to assign e.NewValue in a static field it is saying object reference is required for non static field. 2nd the PropertyToUpdate in my Viewmodel is EventId, and from there how I can use that EventId and where I need to make a call to Domain service with that EventId. If you see my LogEventsViewModel.cs in my question I have 2 properties, View and EventId. When/ where I can update my View property in my ViewModel. Looks like I'm almost there, Thanks in advance for ur reply.

Comment: @ravella, for your first question, checkout the updates I made to my code example above. For your second question, I'd recommend having a method inside your view model that is responsible for making the call to your domain service and in turn calling that method inside the setter of your view model's EventId property.

Answer (score 1):

KodeKreachor is correct, though it may be necessary to set a Bindable attribute on your exposed property. Without it, a property might not always show in the bindable properties of the control, even if it does still work.