# passing data to a mvvm usercontrol

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm writting a form in WPF/c# with the MVVM pattern and trying to share data with a user control. (Well, the User Controls View Model)

I either need to:

1. Create a View model in the parents and bind it to the User Control
2. Bind certain classes with the View Model in the Xaml
3. Be told that User Controls arn't the way to go with MVVM and be pushed in the correct direction. (I've seen data templates but they didn't seem ideal)

The usercontrol is only being used to make large forms more manageable so I'm not sure if this is the way to go with MVVM, it's just how I would of done it in the past.

I would like to pass a class the VM contruct in the Xaml.

```
<TabItem Header="Applicants">
     <Views:ApplicantTabView>
         <UserControl.DataContext>
             <ViewModels:ApplicantTabViewModel Client="{Binding Client} />
         </UserControl.DataContext>
     </Views:ApplicantTabView>
 </TabItem>
```

```cs
public ClientComp Client
    {
        get { return (ClientComp)GetValue(ClientProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClientProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty ClientProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Client", typeof(ClientComp),
                                                                           typeof(ApplicantTabViewModel),
                                                                                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                                                                                           (null));
```

But I can't seem to get a dependancy property to accept non static content.

This has been an issue for me for a while but assumed I'd find out but have failed so here I am here.

Thanks in advance,
Oli

Comment: VMs usually should not be dependency objects

Comment: I don't want the VM to be a DP I just want to be able to share some of the parents classes with the UserControl's VM. If I try and bind normally I get an error that it needs to be a DP.

Comment: Yes, you usually don't bind VMs either (in that direction)

Comment: So if I have a large form with multiple sections and a VM which is getting unmanagable. What is the "industry standard" way of solving this? in Winforms I would of made a UserControl to spit up the forms.

Comment: Well yeah, but you then would bind the DataContext of those user controls to a property of your VM instead of creating a new VM and binding its properties to some other VM.

Comment: What type does your parent class have? What is the ClientComp type and how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question as yours recently: [passing a gridview selected item value to a different ViewModel of different Usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468881/passing-a-gridview-selected-item-value-to-a-different-viewmodel-of-different-use/9470374#9470374)

Essentially setting up a dependency property which allows data from your parent view to persist to your child user control. Abstracting your view into specific user controls and hooking them using dependency properties along with the MVVM pattern is actually quite powerful and recommended for Silverlight/WPF development, especially when unit testing comes into play. Let me know if you'd like any more clarification, hope this helps.

Comment: That's a great help but I think I'm missing something extremely fundamental about Dependency Properties. Could I ping a really simple project over to you? Would be greatly appreciated indeed. (Send something to my Gmail if you don't mind)

Comment: What are you having problems with regarding dependency properties?

Comment: I was having difficuly making the binding (through a DP on the view) between the parent and child a "two way" binding. I made a small project with 1 Window (Plus VM) / 1 User Control (Plus VM) / 1 Simple Entity and attempted to share the entity between the two. I have got the actual project working to a degree now but I think it is far from industry standard.   Thanks for your time though. Oli

Answer (score 6):

Oli - it is OK (actually - recommended) to split portions of the View into UserControl, if UI became too big - and independently you can split the view models to sub view models, if VM became too big.

It appears though that you are doing double-instantiations of your sub VM. There is also no need to create Dependency Property in your VM (actually, I think it is wrong).

In your outer VM, just have the ClientComp a regular property. If you don't intend to change it - the setter doesn't even have to fire a property changed event, although it is recommended.

```
public class OuterVm
{
    public ClientComp Client { get; private set; }

    // instantiate ClientComp in constructor:
    public OuterVm( ) {
        Client = new ClientComp( );
    }
}
```

Then, in the XAML, put the ApplicantTabView, and bind its data context:

```
...
<TabItem Header="Applicants">
    <Views:ApplicantTabView DataContext="{Binding Client}" />
</TabItem>
```