# Simple Windows Phone User Control Databinding Does Not Work

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an issue with something that should be very simple databinding scenario. I want to bind a list of items. I want to create a user control put it in a ItemsControl's template and bind the ItemsControl to some data. I am perfectly happy with one time databinding so I was kind of hoping to avoid learning about dependency properties and all the databinding stuff for this simple scenario.

Here is the XAML for the user control:

```
<TextBlock>Just Something</TextBlock>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace TestWindowsPhoneApplication
{
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public TestData SomeProperty { get; set; }
        public String SomeStringProperty { get; set; }

        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <t:TestControl SomeStringProperty="{Binding Path=SomeString}"></t:TestControl>
            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeString}"></TextBlock>-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace TestWindowsPhoneApplication
{
    public class TestData
    {
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            itemsList.DataContext = new TestData[] { new TestData { SomeString = "Test1" }, new TestData { SomeString = "Test2" } };
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the project I get an error "the parameter is incorrect". I also tried binding directly to the item with SomeProperty={Binding} since that is what I actually want to do but this causes the same error. If I try doing the same thing with the TextBlock control (the commented line) everything works fine.

How can I implement this simple scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a property on your custom control "bindable" you have to make it a dependency property. Check out my answer here for a nice simple example of doing just this on a custom control: [passing a gridview selected item value to a different ViewModel of different Usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468881/passing-a-gridview-selected-item-value-to-a-different-viewmodel-of-different-use/9470374#9470374)

```
public string SomeString
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SomeStringProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SomeStringProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeStringProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SomeString", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomeStringChanged)));

private static void OnSomeStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TestControl)d).OnSomeStringChanged(e);
}

protected virtual void OnSomeStringChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //here you can do whatever you'd like with the updated value of SomeString
    string updatedSomeStringValue = e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: Since I don't have a ViewModel what goes in the place of the ownerType argument ( typeof(LogEvents) )?

Comment: LogEvents is the custom user control type, so that would equate to your TestControl. In my answer I added an example of what your SomeString dependency property would look like in the code-behind of your TestControl.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work now. I intend to change the view of the control (some text and colr) in the property setter. I would be very grateful if you tell me if this is the right place to do this.

Comment: Also OnTrackerInstanceChanged does not compile. Should I write this method myself? Or is it supposed to be OnSomeStringChanged?

Comment: You're right on, that should be OnSomeStringChanged, copy-paste error on my part, I updated my answer above. For your other question, if you aren't using the MVVM pattern (with view models) then I would suggest passing the updated string value to a local method which in turn updates attributes of your control. The MVVM pattern is tailor-made for these types of scenarios though and I would definitely recommend investigating it. It's very powerful and it sets you up very well to take care of these operations via data binding as well as effectively unit test them.

Comment: Yeah it seems like I will have to learn about MVVM despite te fact that I have a single one way databinding in my application:)