# Pass through wpf dependency property of usercontrol to child control

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom  MyControl : UserControl with dependency property

```
string Text
```

Inside the MyControl in XAML I have a TextBox.

I wish to bind the **Text dependency property of MyControl** to the **Text dependency property  of the TextBox**.

What is the best way to do this? Can I declare the dependency property of
MyControl to pass through to the child depenendency property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to assign a `x:Name="root"` attribute to the root of your `MyControl.xaml` file, and then use a binding like this for your `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}" />
```

(You can specify your own name for `root`.)

Comment: But does that implicitly create the DP on the user control. I would still have to declare it in code behind right?

Comment: You absolutely have to declare your property on the user control; there's no implicit creation of a property just because you bind to it.  Your question states that you have a custom control with that dependency property already and is asking for help binding to it; if that's not the case then you should possibly reword your question.

Comment: Nah I was just curious. There are lots of dark corners in WPF. It wouldn't have surprised me if it were possible :)

Comment: This works, but what about when you want to specify a StringFormat in the binding such as: UnitlessValue="{Binding NumberAsPercent, StringFormat=P1}, has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: @GetFuzzy: have you tried `{Binding NumberAsPercent, ElementName=root, StringFormat=P1}`?

Comment: @DanPuzey My StringFormat wasn't working because the dependency property type was a double.  When the dependency property type is a string the above syntax works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468881/passing-a-gridview-selected-item-value-to-a-different-viewmodel-of-different-use/9470374#9470374) details a nice example of how you can accomplish this. You'll essentially have your controls bound to properties on your view models, with the child view model having a dependency property that enables binding on the child control and can push the value to the child's view model. The example is in Silverlight but the implementation is the same for WPF.